# How to print a nested array inside the value of a cloned input object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/7NHXf/2/)

code:

```
//create array with values
thisArray= ['',[]];
thisArray[0] = ['numbers',['one','two','three','four','five']];
// have a clean clone of input
var newElem = $('#input').clone();

//search through aray and print the nested array inside the
//   value of the cloned input
for(i = 0; i<thisArray[0][1].length; i++){

    $(newElem).val(thisArray[0][1][i]);
    $('input.input').last().after(newElem);
}
```

Conditions: I cannot change the HTML or layout of the array.

Question: how can i edit the for loop to display the numbers in the array one after another inside the cloned input field? so the final output will be six input fields with a number in each except the first one.

Comment: Can you please confirm that I understand you correctly? You want to clone an input with id #input and insert that after the last input with class ".input" on the page. You want to display "one", "two", etc. in that cloned input and you want that to happen with a little delay between the numbers, like "one" .... "two" .... "three".

Comment: mostly, i want 6 input fields with a number in each of them except for the first one. I altered the fiddle a little so there would not be more than one element with the same 'id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make five copies in order to insert five new inputs:

```
//create array with values
thisArray= ['',[]];
thisArray[0] = ['numbers',['one','two','three','four','five']];

var newElem;

//search through aray and print the nested array inside the value of the cloned input
for(var i = 0; i<thisArray[0][1].length; i++){
    newElem = $('.input').eq(0).clone();    // <-- cloning moved here!
    newElem.val(thisArray[0][1][i]);
    $('input.input').last().after(newElem);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7NHXf/4/
​

Comment: This is correct and works perfectly but I feel like this would be slower than it could be. Why couldn't i create the var newElem once then edit it and display it with the edits multiple times?

Comment: If you clone it once, you have exactly one input element in the memory. If you want to have multiple inputs on the screen, you just need to make more copies. That's like: If you buy one cheeseburger, you cannot eat that cheeseburger more than once - if you wanna eat more than one cheeseburger, you simply need to buy more. Each copy can be at exactly one place on your page at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Woudn't this work?:

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    $field = $('.field'),
    newFields = [];

for (var i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++) {
    var field = '<input type="text" value="'+ numbers[i] +'" />';
    newFields.push(field);
}

$(newFields.join('')).insertAfter($field);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/7NHXf/9/